# Sending other data through Pyapns (iOS push notifcations) with Django

Tags: ios, django, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to data other data through pyapns? For example, say I have a post model. Each post has a post_id. I would like to send the post_id with the push notification. The user who receives the push notification will receive something like, "Alex commented on your post."

The user will not see the post_id. It is hidden to the user but I would still like to send this extra data so that when the user clicks on the push notification, it leads them to the correct post.

This is what I have in my util.py:

```
import pyapns
import xmlrpclib

class PyapnsWrapper(object):

     def __init__(self, host, app_id, apns_certificate_file, mode='production'):
         self.app_id = app_id
         pyapns.configure({'HOST': host})
         pyapns.provision(app_id,
                          open(apns_certificate_file).read(),
                          mode)

     def notify(self, token, message):
         try:
             pyapns.notify(self.app_id,
                           token,
                           {'aps':{'alert': message}})
         except xmlrpclib.Fault, e:
             print e
```

How could I possibly modify this to send in an extra field with the notify argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

`{'aps':{'alert': message}}`

with

`{'aps':{'alert': message},'post-id':post_id}`.

I'm not familiar with `pyapns` and I don't know python, but the APNS payload format allows to add custom properties to the payload. I'm not sure if my syntax is accurate (as I said I don't know python), but you should get the idea from it.

The JSON payload should look like this :

```
{

    "aps" : {

        "alert" : "Alex commented on your post.",

    },

    "post-id" : 435472

}
```

When the user clicks on the notification and the app is opened, you'll be able to access the custom data this way (`notificationInfo` will contain the `post-id` key with its value):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSDictionary* notificationInfo =
        [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (notificationInfo) {
        [self someProcessing:notificationInfo];
    }
    ...
    return YES;
}
```